# JAVA- Unit Test Cases

Tags: java

I tried to write UTC for following method but not getting the answer

thanks in advance:))

Here's a code snippet,

```
public Map<Integer, Object> getTrack(Long id) throws Exception {
    HashMap<Integer, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    SelectQuery sqr = new SelectQueryImpl(new Table(tracktabledetails.TABLE));
    sq.addSelectColumn(new Column(null, "*"));

    Criteria cr = new Criteria(new Column(tracktabledetails.TABLE, 
                            tracktabledetails.TRACKID), id,
                            QueryConstants.EQUAL);

    sqr.setCriteria(cr);

    DataObject dataobj = PersistenceCacheUtil.getSelectSimple().get(sqr);

    Iterator it = (Iterator) dataobj.getRows(tracktabledetails.TABLE);

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Row rw = (Row) it.next();
        Integer index = (Integer) rw.get(tracktabledetails.INDEX);
        Integer days = (Integer) rw.get(tracktabledetails.DAYS);
        String type = (String) rw.get(tracktabledetails.TYPE);
        Long templateId = (Long) rw.get(tracktabledetails.EMAILTEMPLATEID);
        Long mailProfileId = (Long) rw.get(tracktabledetails.MAILPROFILEID);
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(days);
        list.add(templateId);
        list.add(type);
        list.add(mailProfileId);
        map.put(index, list);
    }

    return map;
}
```

```
@Test
    public void getTrack ()throws Exception
    {
        HashMap<Integer, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,Object>();

        //PowerMockito.whenNew(SelectQueryImpl.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(selectQueryImpl);
        //PowerMockito.whenNew(Criteria.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(criteria);  
        PowerMockito.when(PersistenceCacheUtil.getSelectSimple()).thenReturn(persistence);
        PowerMockito.when(persistence.get(selectQueryImpl)).thenReturn(dataObject);  //******************

        PowerMockito.when(dataObject.getRows(tracktabledetails.TABLE)).thenReturn(iterator);

        PowerMockito.when(iterator.next()).thenReturn(row); 
        PowerMockito.when(row.get(tracktabledetails.INDEX)).thenReturn(index); 
        PowerMockito.when(row.get(tracktabledetails.DAYS)).thenReturn(days); 
        PowerMockito.when(row.get(tracktabledetails.TYPE)).thenReturn(type); 
        PowerMockito.when(row.get(tracktabledetails.EMAILTEMPLATEID)).thenReturn(templateId); 
        PowerMockito.when(row.get(tracktabledetails.MAILPROFILEID)).thenReturn(mailProfileId);

        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(days);
        list.add(templateId);
        list.add(type);
        list.add(mailProfileId);

        map.put(index, list);


        Map <Integer, Object> actualMap = communicationPlansUtil.getTrackTemplateInfo(id);
        System.out.println("actualMap :" +actualMap);
        System.out.println("map :"+map);
        assertEquals(map, actualMap);       
    }
```

console output:

```
actualMap :{}
map :{1=[4, 1, type, 3]}
```

Comment: Can you show us the tries that didn't work? Just edit your answer and show us at least one test case you have written and that didn't work and please tell us how and why it didn't work. Thanks...

Comment: i post my ans please have a look

Comment: you just provide my solution as answer .